# Debian 11 no longer automatically receiving static DHCP IP address, dhclient must be started manually

Tags: linux, debian, linux-networking, virtual-machines, dhcp

I am hosting a Debian 11 (no desktop environment) virtual machine on Windows Server 2012 with Hyper-V. This is on a company network with its own DHCP system and the MAC address of the VM is registered with a static IP address. The machine has been working fine since November and was originally installed with Debian 10. I recently went through the process of doing a full upgrade from Debian 10 to Debian 11 without reinstalling. The upgrade took a while but went fine, once I upgraded I realized that the PHP package server (packages.sury.org) was still set to be for Debian 10, so I updated it to pull packages for Debian 11 and began the update of the PHP packages I had. I was connected via SSH and before it completed, the terminal froze and I could not ping the server. When I logged in through Hyper-V, the VM had restarted and I could not ping any websites or IP addresses. The eth0 adapter starts as `DOWN` and when brought back up, I would only get an IPv6 address and not IPv4.

After a significant amount of troubleshooting, the only solution I found was to manually invoke the dhclient command (`sudo dhclient eth0`) and this finally pulls up the correct static IP address I had before the issue started. However, this is only a temporary fix and I have to do it again if/when the VM is restarted. I don't think that upgrading to Debian 11 caused the issue since I had been using it for a few hours at this point and restarted a few times. It only began once I tried updating the PHP packages, but I don't really know why that would cause the DHCP to stop working. The VM is still registered with my company's network.

Long story short, how do I get the VM to automatically get its static address again, and how do I make sure it starts in the UP state once the VM boots? If any more information is needed, please let me know. I added the previously mentioned command to the crontab to run on boot and that resolved it, but I was hoping to find a solution rather than a band-aid fix.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is addressed in the article: [Strange extra long Linux MAC address in DHCP active leases](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2288212-strange-extra-long-linux-mac-address-in-dhcp-active-leases).

Basically, in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, add the line:

```
send dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;
```

Comment: This fixed my issue on Debian 12. Had this problem on two different systems (on the same network). Suspected the router to be the culprit but windows gets a lease just fine.